# How do I remove a margin property when the element begins on a new line?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have `figcaption` elements in which I use `cite` for the photos’ source. So an image caption looks like this:

`<figcaption>Caption. <cite>Photographer.</cite></figcaption>`

Inspired by the way the *[New York Times](https://nytimes.com)* formats their photo captions and photo sources, I’ve made the `cite` elements a bit smaller and gray, and with a bit of space between the “actual” caption and the citation:

`cite {margin-left: .12rem}`

However, in cases where the `cite` element starts on a new line, the margin is still there. This doesn’t look good:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IORjK.png)

If `cite` weren’t within the `figcaption`, I would of course just add `margin-right` to `figcaption`. Yet it is. So what’s the solution? Is there a way to target the non-`cite` part of the `figcaption` without wrapping it in its own `span`?

Comment: I suggest you put a sample code to get a better answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add your code so we can see what's wrong. Here's a basic figcaption using margin on the `cite` and no issues

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 612px;
  height: 408px;
}

cite {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/black-white-tiger-picture-id954560222?k=6&m=954560222&s=612x612&w=0&h=SMzlLQeIxj5v6zoJPmTxV7zdk17d7LBNmzJAjYVrfI8="
         alt="Tiger" id="pic1" width="612" height="408">
    <figcaption>This is a black and white picture of a Tiger. He has his mouth open and is day dreaming about Roy Horn. The margins look good on this caption.<cite>Some Photgrapher and another photographer and another.</cite></figcaption>
</figure>
```

You also don't need to add a margin to separate the `cite` from the `figcaption` if you add a space after `<cite>` it will separate the two.

`<cite> Some Photgrapher and another photographer and another.</cite>`